# Angular hashbangs ui-router - home state

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ui-router in Angularjs and I have the following routes (as part of my `app.js` file):

```
...
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

$stateProvider

.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    data: { public: true } 
})

.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    data: { login: true } 
})
...
```

I have decided to keep the # in my routes because ui-router doesn't work too well with the html5 setting for routing without the hash.

**Question:** When I navigate to `localhost:8080/` I would expect my home state to kick in but it goes to `/dashboard` (the otherwise route). I can only access the root of my site with `localhost:8080/#/` - is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer for the question, but you might want to take a look at http://angular-route-segment.com for this case, as it works on top of built-in `ngRoute` module which plays well with html5 mode as well.